Dell Latitude 5340 Wifi card not working - Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz [8086:4090] Error -110
I have a problem with Dell Latitude 5340 13" and 5440 14", Wifi working on Windows 11, using latest Ubuntu 24.04 and tested with 6.8.0-1014-oem and 6.8.0-47-generic with the same error, both laptops are Ubuntu Certified... Please help!
uname -r
6.8.0-1014-oem

cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"

lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz [8086:4090]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

rfkill list
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lshw -c network
  *-network NO RECLAMADO    
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 14.3
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:14.3

modinfo iwlwifi
filename: /lib/modules/6.8.0-1014-oem/ubuntu/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko.zst
version: iwlwifi-stack-public:master:11510:0106cce5
license: GPL
description: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux

cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf 
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211 options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1

modprobe options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0 swcrypto=0
modprobe: FATAL: Module options not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-1014-oem

dmesg | grep iwlwifi
    ...
    [ 18.222478] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110


Power off, unplug, press and hold power button for 30 seconds, plug in and boot

Sorry but the problem happens in other Dell Latitude 5350 and 5440 in our company, I dont think repluging of the wifi card must solve the problem.

Unplug power cord and hold power button down for 30 seconds or disable hybrid shutdown in Windows
